# Jenkins 2 Build Processors for one Job

Tags: jenkins

i have a little problem with an multibranch Pipeline Job. Following problem I have a job that always requires 2 build processors. Unfortunately I don't want to unlock more build processors in Jenkins but want to know why Jenkins always uses 2 build cores for this job. Can anyone help me why jenkins uses 2 processors for this job at the same time ?

```
pipeline {
    options { disableConcurrentBuilds() }
    agent { label 'myServer' }

    stages {

        stage('helloworld') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'ubuntu:16.04'
                    label 'myServer'
                }
            }
            steps {
                dir('build') {
                    sh 'npm i'
                    sh 'npm run gulp clean:all'
                    sh 'npm run gulp ci:all'
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option `reuseNode` for docker agents which is false by default. I assume that this may be the reason why jenkins needs 2 build cores (one for each docker agent) in your case, altough I'm not sure.

The option can be found in the Jenkins Declarative Syntax Documentation ( https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#common-options ) at Sections > Agent > Common Options > reuseNode.

Could you try with reuseNode enabled and report whether it solved the problem?